# problem with hide/show in jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm working on some kind of gallery. Found cool ready solution but i want to make some modifications, and i'm stuck.

http://www.rareclips.ayz.pl/test/

How i want this to work:
When you click on and image it should change the image on the right and make one of hidden div's visible.

The problem is that i have to hide all the divs on page load and show only specific div inside this hidden div on image click.

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){

//Larger thumbnail preview 

$("ul.thumb li").hover(function() {
 $(this).css({'z-index' : '10'});
 $(this).find('img').addClass("hover").stop()
  .animate({
   marginTop: '-110px',
   marginLeft: '-110px', 
   top: '50%', 
   left: '50%', 
   width: '200px',
   height: '200px',
   padding: '5px'
  }, 200);

 } , function() {
 $(this).css({'z-index' : '0'});
 $(this).find('img').removeClass("hover").stop()
  .animate({
   marginTop: '0', 
   marginLeft: '0',
   top: '0', 
   left: '0', 
   width: '150px',
   height: '150px',
   padding: '10px'
  }, 400);
});

//Swap Image on Click

 $("ul.thumb li a").click(function() {

  var mainImage = $(this).attr("href"); //Find Image Name
                $("#main_view img").attr({ src: mainImage });

                return false;
 });


});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
//      $('#slickbox').hide();
      $('a.slick-toggle').click(function() {

        var dataID = $(this).attr("data-id");
        $('#slickbox').hide();
        $("#slickbox.div[data-id=" + dataID + "].slickbox").show('slow');
        return false;
    });
});
</script>

</head><body>
<div class="container">

<ul class="thumb">
 <li><a class="slick-toggle" href="./index_pliki/max1.jpg" data-id="1"><img src="./index_pliki/min1.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
 <li><a class="slick-toggle" href="./index_pliki/max2.jpg" data-id="2"><img src="./index_pliki/min2.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
 <li><a href="./index_pliki/max3.jpg" data-id="3"><img src="./index_pliki/min3.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
 <li><a href="./index_pliki/max4.jpg" data-id="4"><img src="./index_pliki/min4.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
</ul>

<div id="main_view">

        <a href="index.htm" id="slick-up"><img src="index_pliki/max1.jpg" alt=""/></a>
 <small style="float: right; color: rgb(153, 153, 153);">
                       </small>
</div>

<div id="wiecej">       

<div id="slickbox">

<a id="someID" class="slick-toggle" data-id="1" href="#">Show/Hide</a>
<div id="someOtherID" class="slickbox" data-id="1" style="display: none;">
  1
</div>

<a id="someID" class="slick-toggle" data-id="2" href="#">Show/Hide</a>
<div id="someOtherID" class="slickbox" data-id="2" style="display: none;">
  2
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please visit http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't make things visible inside an hidden element:

```
$('#slickbox').hide();
```

This hides the div with the id `slickbox` and all it's children.
Change your click handler like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a.slick-toggle').click(function() {
    var dataID = $(this).attr("data-id");
    $('#slickbox div.slickbox').hide();
    $("#slickbox div[data-id=" + dataID + "].slickbox").show('slow');
    return false;
  });
});
```

And note the missing dot between `#slickbox div`